# Can't delete a block (SKU number) from product page. (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I want to remove the SKU numbers from the product page, so I copy the content of `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` to `<vendor>/<my-theme-dir>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` and I replace the following lines...

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

... to the following:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true"/>
```

After saving, I do the following commands

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL en_US
```

and I delete the content of `pub/static/frontend/<my-theme>` and `var/view/preprocessed/css/frontend/<my-theme>`

I also tried

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL en_US
```

However, the SKU number is still there:
[image]

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try add bellow code to your theme default.xml file in body tag

> `<referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the line directly after the opening `<body>` tag in `<vendor>/<my-theme-dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` but no luck. :(

Comment: If you are use custom theme then you have to add to theme default.xml file. you can not change directly vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Do not outcomment the block, but only the arguments, see:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type"> 
                        <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true"/>
                            <!--<arguments>
                                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
                            </arguments>-->
                        </block>
```

Comment: Welcome on Magento SE. Please answer in English only.

Comment: I took the liberty to translate the post from German ;)

Comment: Sorry, now in english ...

I also have to remove the SKU and it worked with the
<ReferenceBlock name = "product.info.sku" remove = "true" />

I did not comment on the whole block. Just the arguments.
And there the line inserted:
<ReferenceBlock name = "product.info.sku" remove = "true" />
That was all, not even the cache was needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Fortunately I don't have to fix the issue anymore. / Vielen dank für Ihre Antwort. Zum Glück muss ich das Problem nicht mehr lösen. (Entschuldigung für mein slechtes Deutsch.)

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap the remove code to get this to work on my theme.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I replaced the content of `<vendor>/<my-theme-dir>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` to the code in your answer, added the `<?xml>` and `<page>` tags around them (as in the answer of @Aaron-Allen), but it still doesn't work. :( Is your theme based on the Luma theme?

Comment: Yes, i have a custom theme that is inheriting from luma. Since Aaron Allen and me both are going down the same road for an answer, i wonder if the block that is displaying your sku is a different block. Or if there is another sku block being added. One thing to make sure of is that your XML changes are showing up at all. Can you make any change to the site with XML? You might have another problem if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

catalog_product_view.xml in `{theme_dir}/Magento_Catalog/layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I replaced the content of `catalog_product_view.xml` in my theme with the xml in your answer, but unfortunately it's not working. :(

Comment: I can confirm that the above works, I use it in my own store. Make sure you have flushed the cache. If you're not in developer mode, delete contents of pub/static and var/view_preprocessed as well.